# AWS Configure in single line command

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, command-line

I'm trying to configure my AWS account using Ansible and from what I know it needs to be on one line (unless theres a way to pres "ENTER" progomatically in the Windows command).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not just have Ansible create the `.aws/config` and `.aws/credentials` files directly. That's all the `aws configure` command is doing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this command**

```
$aws configure set aws_access_key_id default_access_key
$ aws configure set aws_secret_access_key default_secret_key
$ aws configure set default.region us-west-2
```

*or*

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id <key_id> && aws configure set aws_secret_access_key <key> && aws configure set default.region us-east-1
```

**For more details use this link**
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/configure/set.html

Answer (score 0):

With `aws configure` we can also set values interactively, but with `aws configure set` we can set the values directly.

> SYNOPSIS
>             aws configure set varname value [--profile profile-name]

```
OPTIONS
varname (string) The name of the config value to set. 
value (string) The value to set.
```

For example.

```
aws configure --profile myprofile set region us-east-1
aws configure --profile myprofile set aws_access_key_id XXXXXXXXXXX
aws configure --profile myprofile set aws_secret_access_key YYYYYYYY
```

Alternately, you may also use.

```
aws configure set profile.myprofile.region us-east-1
aws configure set profile.myprofile.aws_access_key_id XXXXXXXXXXX
aws configure set profile.myprofile.aws_secret_access_key YYYYYYYY
```